# rqt_publisher genpy.Time[0]

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How i can publish a msg with rqt_publisher with current time added to the stamp in a msg?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227039/rqt_publisher-genpy.time%5B0%5D/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For values, one can use any valid python expression, including functions from math, time, and random modules (without module prefix). Thus, for time, one should use `time()` in the secs field of the time stamp and `time()*1e9 % 1e9` for the nsecs field. `time()` returns the seconds since epoch as float.

---

Originally posted by [rhaschke](https://answers.ros.org/users/26329/rhaschke/) with karma: 71 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2